# how can I handle exceptions in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, exception, error-handling

I am working in MVC3 Application. I am struggle to handle exceptions in my controller.

Here My Account controller is,

```
public ActionResult Register(NewRegister model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (!IsUserLoginExist(model.Email))
        {
            AccountServiceHelper.CreatePerson(model);
            return RedirectToAction("RegistrationConfirmation", "Account");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("","Email Address already taken.");
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

After I validate `IsUserLoginExist` I am just calling the Helper Class i.e. `AccountServiceHelper` for consuming a web service method like `CreatePerson`.

My Helper class looks like this:

```
public static void CreatePerson(NewRegister model)
{
    try
    {
        try
        {
            var FirstName = model.FristName;
            var LastName = model.LastName;
            var Email = model.Email;
            var Role = model.Role;
            var Password = model.Password;
            .....
            .....
            service.CreatePerson(model);
            service.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) 
        {

        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```

My problem is how can I handle Exception in helper class and return to the controller.

Comment: Do you want to handle the exception in your helper method and then return (bubble up) the exception to your controller, or do you want to handle and suppress it in the helper method?

Comment: Yes i want to handle the exception in my helper class and return to my controller..In other words simply i want to propagate the exception in my UI..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to handle the exception at your controller:

```
public static void CreatePerson(NewRegister model)
{
    var FirstName = model.FristName;
    var LastName = model.LastName;
    var Email = model.Email;
    var Role = model.Role;
    var Password = model.Password;
    .....
    .....
    service.CreatePerson(model);
    service.close();
}
```

and then:

```
public ActionResult Register(NewRegister model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!IsUserLoginExist(model.Email))
            {
                AccountServiceHelper.CreatePerson(model);
                return RedirectToAction("RegistrationConfirmation", "Account");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Email Address already taken.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said, you throw it from your helper class using this method:

```
public static void CreatePerson(NewRegister model)
{
    try
    {
        var FirstName = model.FristName;
        var LastName = model.LastName;
        var Email = model.Email;
        var Role = model.Role;
        var Password = model.Password;
        .....
        .....
        service.CreatePerson(model);
        service.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e) 
    {
        // handle it here if you want to i.e. log

        throw e; // bubble it to your controller
    }
}
```

If an exception occurs in your helper class, and you don't specifically catch it in your helper class, it will bubble up to your controller anyway.  So if you don't want to handle it in your helper class, there's no need to catch it as it will end up in your controller anyway.

Answer (score 0):

throw it from your helper class